# What features does the X-Box One require internet access for?

Tags: xbox-one

Since they first announced the XBox One at E3 there's been crap loads of changes that I began to just tune out until it came out. I need to know exactly which features require internet access since the XBox One was announced. I would buy one for my dad, but I would rather like to avoid anything that requires the internet with him (cause then if he is using something that requires the internet I'm going to be called up every time there is a drop out). So I need to know what he would miss out and if he actually needs it?

Does the Xbox One require an Internet connection? If so, what for? Is it detrimental to the user if they do not have internet plugged in all the time.

Comment: those of you voting to close just remember its released in aussie land right now. and i'm pretty sure its the same setup as 360. you can play games offline, but thats pretty much it.

Comment: @Memor-X - The list is pretty simple.   Anything that requires you be connect to Xbox Live requires an interent connection.  Clearly this would mean internet connect services on the console itself.  So the only feature that would not require interent access playing an xbox game ( after the day one patch that is required ).  The problem you will run into is that Blu-ray feature will require updates ( nature of the format ) and its likely games will require you to install updates.  **You might want to do some research before a purchase**

Comment: @Memor-X There are a LOT of things that the Xbox One will not be able to do without the internet. Playing Games is not on that list, but most games nowadays have updates and patches that are pushed only through the internet. Some Blu-Ray Disks could ask for an internet connection but it is not mandatory. Xbox Live is also a requirement for almost any feature that requires internet access, As Ramhound said look into the system but do be aware that the PS4 is no longer free for online and requires online for many of the same features. No-internet consoles are best made yourself anymore ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Microsoft's official statement post-the E3](http://news.xbox.com/2013/06/update) uproar, back on the 19th of June:

> **An internet connection will not be required to play offline Xbox One
>   games** – After a one-time system set-up with a new Xbox One, you can
>   play any disc based game without ever connecting online again. There
>   is no 24 hour connection requirement and you can take your Xbox One
>   anywhere you want and play your games, just like on Xbox 360.

<sup>(their emphasis)</sup>

That "one-time system setup" includes an initial day one update of about 500MB that the console needs to download to be fully functional, but you don't need to sign in to your console or Xbox Live to receive that update, the console will find and download it as soon as it is first internet connected. (source: this was the first thing my Xbox One did yesterday after switching on and checking my wired internet connection, and before taking me through the initial set up of signing in and calibrating the Kinect).

Of course that statement was published under the name of Don Mattrick, then President of Microsoft's Interactive Entertainment Business, who has since [left Microsoft to join Zynga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Mattrick#Zynga), so I can understand anyone worrying if that statement is still true.

Marc Whitten, who is still, Microsoft's Xbox One chief product officer was [interviewed by Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/xbox-one-drm-reversal-cuts-features-requires-one-time-514419715?rev=1371676969), and this is what was said:

> ...your new Xbox console would have to connect online once in order to
>   do the things Microsoft described today. And then you can keep it
>   offline and play games without re-connecting to the Internet forever.

I don't believe that there has been anything since contradicting that statement.

(Addendum: it was briefly possible to [pull down the day one patch on a PC and transfer to an offline Xbox](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2013-11-21-how-to-update-xbox-one-without-connecting-it-to-the-internet) on a USB stick, but Microsoft have just removed that facility from their website, and have said that Microsoft Support will take people through a manual update process if necessary)

Lots of optional apps and services do require an internet connection, but these are optional parts of the experience. Some examples:

- Skype requires an internet connection, so that it can do video
  calling and messaging.
- Video streaming services, such as Netflix,
  Amazon Streaming and Hulu, require an internet connection to stream
  movies.
- Multiplayer gaming over Xbox Live requires an internet
  connection to connect the players. Some future games may be multi-player only (eg Titanfall) and so won't work without an internet connection.